# IEEE 754 Denormalized Decimal Converting to Half-Point Binary

Tags: assembly, x86, denormalized

I am trying to convert 0.0000211 to binary. Here is what I understand so far:

E = -bias + 1. bias = 15, E = -14

Sign bit and exponent = 0.

So I have:

0 00000 ??????????

With the half-point format being 1 sign bit, 5 exponent bits, and 10 fraction bits.

My question is how can I find the fraction of this denormalized number? What does E, and the bias mean in this context? Any help would be appreciated

Note: I need to be able to do this manually for my final.

Comment: https://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/frombase10.htm

Comment: I can convert between hex/binary/decimal fine, but I am having trouble with denormalized numbers. Are you saying that it is the same method as those described in your link? Thank you for your comment

Comment: What does denormal mean?  means you cant normalize the number into the specified format, the number is so small that as you shift the decimal point (adjust the exponent) you hit the exponent limit before the number is in the form of +/-1.xxxxx binary (for IEEE754).

Comment: so the first thing you need to do IMO is convert it from decimal to binary, THEN try to fit it into whatever encoding, not sure how you would go from decimal to encoding without converting it to binary first anyway.

Comment: If I wanted to fit 1234 decimal into a byte I would first convert it to 0x4D2 then decide if it fits in a byte...(sure in that case I could take the shortcut of is it bigger than 256)

Comment: I see what you mean now. I mostly have trouble with the first step of converting the denormalized decimal to binary. Thank you for your insight

Comment: it is denormal if you cant normalize it, which has to do with the floating point format IEEE754 in this case.  If I only have two decimal numbers to represent the year in some software does that mean we as humans cannot exist more than 99 years on the planet?  Nope that just means that software wont work we can count well past 99, you can convert any decimal number into binary, that doesnt mean that any binary number will fit in any binary FORMAT like fit in an 8 bit register or fit in a 32 bit IEEE float, etc.

Comment: for example in decimal your number is +2.11*10^-6 right?  so your unbiased exponent is a -6 your sign is 0 and mantissa is 211 in some floating point format i made up just now.  Repeat that for  the binary representation, you will get 0.00000something,  how many negative powers of 2 do you need to normalize that THEN see if that fits in your format start unbiased then IEEE likes to not put the pure exponent in there at least not for 32, 64, and 80 bit formats. I assume for this half thing it is the same...

Comment: I updated my post to make the half-point format clearer for you. Also could you explain further what you meant by the mantissa is 211? is it 0.211? This is what you would convert to get it into binary?

Comment: is there such a thing as denormalized decimal?  you would need a base 10 floating point format and then IF it doesnt fit into that format you would then talk about denormalized representation, in this case 2.11 * 10^6 is a valid base 10 notation for that number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mantissa (OPs ? bits) of a half, float or double is normalized to remove the leading zeros. Usually this is done until the number is, 1.0 <= number < 2.0. But in this case the number is in the sub-normals range (The exponent is 00000 as you've already established. Which means the original number was less than the minimum normal of 6.10352 × 10^−5, ie when you're trying to shift to make the number  1.0 <= number < 2.0, you hit the exponents minimum limit), in this case they shift 15 times, ie multiply by 2^15 and store as many bits after the point as possible (for half floats this is 10bits). Doing this means they can store very small numbers, because for the sub-normal range they have an implicit 0. in front of the mantissa when restoring the number and they allow leading zeros on the mantissa.

So 0.0000211 = b'0.000000000000000101100001111111111100111...

2^15 * 0.0000211 = 0.6914048 = b'0.101100001111111111100111...

We store 1011000011 because the sub normal range removes the implicit 0. (ie for 0.XXXXXXXXXX we only store the Xs)

So in this case the mantissa (OPs ? bits) are 1011000011

```
sign   exp      mantissa
0      00000    1011000011
```

This can be checked with python using numpy and struct

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import struct
>>> a=struct.pack("H",int("0000001101010000",2))
>>> np.frombuffer(a, dtype =np.float16)[0]
2.116e-05
```

So for your final...
At the very least you're going to need to learn how to turn a decimal less than 1.0 into a binary, and remember a few rules. You seem to be on top of calculating the exponent.

Have a look at...

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128204/how-to-convert-from-floating-point-binary-to-decimal-in-half-precision16-bits

One of the answers to this question has python code for the whole conversion. Which may be useful for learning.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of your number going to convert 0.2 decimal to binary by hand.

Starting with a program to give me some fractions in base 10, probably a better way to do this, the link I sent doesnt work that works for whole numbers.

```
1/2 0.50000000
1/4 0.25000000
1/8 0.12500000
1/16 0.06250000
1/32 0.03125000
1/64 0.01562500
1/128 0.00781250
1/256 0.00390625
```

so:

```
0.2 - 0.5 no 
0.2 - 0.25 no
0.2 - 0.125 = 0.075
0.075 - 0.0625 = 0.0125
0.0125 - 0.03125 no
0.0125 - 0.015625 no
0.0125 - 0.00781250 = 0.0046875
0.0046875 - 0.00390625 = 0.00078125
0.00078125 - 0.001953125 no
0.00078125 - 0.0009765625 no
0.00078125 - 0.00048828125 yes
```

I happen to know this cannot be represented exactly in binary it is a 
repeating number so the above tells me:

```
0.0011001100110011...
```

Is the binary number for 0.2 in base 10.

Now to normalize this I need 1.xxxx so I shift left 3 and get

```
1.1001100110011 * 2^(-3)
```

IEEE 754 single precision format (mantissa and fraction are the same thing)

```
seeeeeeeemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
```

Positive number so the sign s is zero

exponent is 2 to the power e-127

so we add 127 bias to -3 and get 124 0x7c

note since the 1.xxxx is implied no reason to waste the 1 that is removed we just put the fraction in.

```
0 01111100 10011001100110011001100
0011 1110 0100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100
0x3E4CCCCC
```

Now I cheated and let the computer convert this for me and got:

```
0 01111100 10011001100110011001101
0x3E4CCCCD
```

and that makes sense because before we chop of the end we have 11001 that last bit being chopped off is greater than or equal to half our base so we round up if we want to round that makes it a 1101.  When we have base ten to round up we need equal to or half the base so 5  0.105 rounds up to 0.11.  so in binary 0.11001 rounds up to 0.1101.

so half point format appears to be

seeeeemmmmmmmmmm

and the bias is 2^(e-15)

so we add 15 to -3 we get 12

s is 0 it is positive e is 12 and m is I assume without the implied 1 bit
so

```
0 01100 1001100110
0011 0010 0110 0110
0x3266
```

where it gets chopped off was a 0 so it doesnt round up assuming a round up rounding mode...

so that is a normalized version of 0.2 in 16 bit IEEE floating point format.

Now if you read wikipedia which is good enough to understand this, if 
when you normalize this to 1.xxxxx you will shift left (or right if greater than 1.xxxx, left if less than 1.xxxx which it is in this case) some number N bits to do that so your number is 1.xxxx times 2^(-N) as shown in the wikipedia page

```
Emin = 000012 − 011112 = −14
```

So an N of 14 is the worst case you can have if you have to shift more than 14 bits you cannot normalize this number.  so they have a case for this shown in wikipedia, they call it subnormal same as denormal.  you shift it 14 bits to the left which is implied by the 2^-14 so you convert your binary number into 0.xxxxxxxxxx * 2^-14, whatever the first ten xxxxx bits that is your mantissa/fraction.  and the exponent in the encoding is a special number 00000

so 0 00000 xxxxxxxxxx is the encoding for a denormal in IEEE 754 half point binary.

Comment: duh,  2^16 * 0.2 = 13107.2 = 0x3333 shifted right 16 is 0.001100110011 thats the shortcut, thanks Clayton...